# How do I prove that $[0,1]$ is convex?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I am having trouble with bounding the upper bound. Since the requirement is

$$\forall t \in [0,1], \forall u,v \in C = [0,1] \to tu + (1-t)v \in C$$

Therefore, I need 
$$tu + (1-t)v \leq 1$$

but I can only bound it with $2$, as in $tu \leq 1$ and $(1-t)v \leq 1$ then $tu + (1-t)v \leq 1+ 1 = 2$.

Comment: What is $a$ doing here?

Comment: @dmtri Given that what you wrote is what the OP has to prove, I don't see how your comment is in any way useful.

Comment: You recieved 5 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, you should upvote all the useful answers and accept the answer that is most useful to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without loss of generality, let $0\le u\le v\le 1$. Then:
$$\color{red}0\le u=tu+(1-t)u\le \color{red}{tu+(1-t)v}\le tv+(1-t)v=v\le \color{red}1.$$

Answer (score 5):

for showing that $C=[0.1]$ is a convex set,suppose that $0\lt t\lt1$ and $x ,y \in C$,we want to show that $tx+(1-t)y \in C$.
We have$$0\leq tx+(1-t)y\leq t+(1-t)=1$$.
Therefore $tx+(1-t)y\in C$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: use that $u, v \in C$, i.e. $\leq 1$.

Answer (score 3):

You have to prove that

$$tu + (1-t)v\leq 1$$

You can do that by using the facts that:

- $u\leq 1$
- $t\geq 0$
- Therefore, $ut \leq t$

and doing something similar with $(1-t)v$.

Answer (score 2):

$$tu+(1-t)v\le \max{\{tu+(1-t)u, tv+(1-t)v\}}=\max{\{u,v\}}\le 1$$
Similarly $tu+(1-t)v\ge \min{\{u,v\}}\ge 0$.